# Not sure why my comment got deleted

Tags: support, comments

I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465711/how-to-delete-an-undeletable-file-from-windows-8-1/32465851?noredirect=1#comment52793718_32465851) on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465711/how-to-delete-an-undeletable-file-from-windows-8-1) question but I can't see the particular comment any more.

The content of the comment was:

[How to Fix Problems with Windows](http://www.tweakbit.com/land/fix-my-pc/support?build=7fdFMP&instructions=1&exit=1&utm_source=sevenforums.com&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=Sevenforums.1)
I suggest you take a [data back up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup).

I would like to know:

- Has the comment been deleted for reasons of moderation?
- Did it got messed up in any way?
- Is it possible to retrieve it back in any way?

Comment: That is not a programming question anyway and doesn't belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: The question was off topic, yet you joyfully answered it with a link to a product.  Do you want spammers?  Because this is how you get spammers.

Comment: @Will - I deleted the answer when I realized my mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was flagged as linking to a potential malware site so I deleted it.

Comments are ephemeral so if it's not malware then repost the comment. However, it's likely to get flagged again, especially as the question is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks. I realize the question is off-topic and as the question was put on-hold(rightly so), I deleted my answer.